# JSP - Help in generating fixed number of link in pagination

Tags: java, jsp, pagination, jstl, el

my pagination works good but I'm not able to understand how generate a fixed number of links to the pages.
For example, I need to have 5 fixed links in this way: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 > 
if I click on the third page I will see always 5 links: < 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 -7 >

Now with my algorithm I'm only able to generate all the links, but I have no idea how create what I have explained above.
This is my code(only for href generation):

```
<div class="pageBoxRight">
 <c:if test="${param.pageNumber > 1}">
 <a href="javascript: previousRecords();" class="previous"><em>previous</em></a>
 </c:if>
 <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${tot + 1}" step="1" varStatus ="status">
 <a href="javascript: goToPage(${i});" id="paginator${i}" class="pageNumber"><span class="pageNumberRight">${i}</span></a>
 </c:forEach>
 <c:if test="${param.pageNumber < tot}">
 <a href="javascript: nextRecords();" class="next"><em>next</em></a>
 </c:if>
</div>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It get complicated.

```html
<c:set var="p" value="${param.pageNumber}" /> <%-- current page (1-based) --%>
<c:set var="l" value="5" /> <%-- amount of page links to be displayed --%>
<c:set var="r" value="${l / 2}" /> <%-- minimum link range ahead/behind --%>
<c:set var="t" value="${tot}" /> <%-- total amount of pages --%>

<c:set var="begin" value="${((p - r) > 0 ? ((p - r) < (t - l + 1) ? (p - r) : (t - l)) : 0) + 1}" />
<c:set var="end" value="${(p + r) < t ? ((p + r) > l ? (p + r) : l) : t}" />

<c:forEach begin="${begin}" end="${end}" var="page">
    ${page}...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yes, your solution is ok when I visit intermediate page, for example when I'm on the page numebr 3:  1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5, but when I'm on the first page I see only the next two page: 1 - 2 - 3    How can be generalized your condition ?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Fixed it :)

Comment: Nice. FYI when l=5 and current page is 3, this example shows a link to page 0 (5/2=2.5, 3-2.5=0.5) and also adds 6th displayed page. Page 0 can be avoided simply by changing the amount of links to 4 or 6 or by changing 1st comparison to ${(p - r) >=1 ?...

Comment: Did you intend for the "l" value to be changed? FYI when l=10 and p=6, begin is negative causing the loop and JSP to fail