# How to retrieve segment of an ArrayList in JSP with Taglib

Tags: jsp, arraylist, jsp-tags, taglib

I have an ArrayList which is set as an attribute of the response object that is passed to a JSP.

I want to retrieve it's values in parts. I.e. the first 10 items, next 10 items. Or all items from 10th to 'end of list'.

Is there a tag library for this (which would be best).

Otherwise I have a few ideas for how to do this with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `begin` and `end` attributes of the [JSTL `c:forEach`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) for this.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" begin="0" end="9">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

The above example displays the first 10 items. *Note that the `end` is inclusive.*

You can even use EL in those attributes.

```
request.setAttribute("firstrow", 0);
request.setAttribute("rowcount", 10);
```

---

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item" begin="${firstrow}" end="${firstrow + rowcount - 1}">
    ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, pagination at database level is much more memory efficient than pagination at session/request level.

#### See also:

- [ResultSet to Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986998/resultset-to-pagination)
- [Displaying fixed number of page numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517845/jsp-help-in-generating-fixed-number-of-link-in-pagination)

Comment: Thanks as always. I have one place which requires something like "pagination" and this will work perfectly. But in general I will look up db pagination.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with two "See also" links which may be useful with regard to DB pagination.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for pagination, I would suggest using the   [Display Tag Library](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/).

```
<display:table name="list" pagesize="10">
      <display:column property="list.prop1" title="Prop1" />
      <display:column property="list.prop2" title="Prop2" />
      <display:column property="list.prop3" title="Prop3" />
      <display:column property="list.prop1" title="Prop4" />
   </display:table>
```