# JSTL help with pagination

Tags: java, pagination, jstl

I've taken the code from BalusC here: [JSP - Help in generating fixed number of link in pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517845/jsp-help-in-generating-fixed-number-of-link-in-pagination)

All fine, except I'd like to know what this means:

```
<c:set var="begin" value="${(p - r) > 0 ? ((p - r) < (t - l + 1) ? (p - r) : (t - l + 1)) : 1}" />
<c:set var="end" value="${(p + r) < t ? ((p + r) > l ? (p + r) : l) : t}" />
```

I seem to get a page 0 when I hit page 3, and I don't want a page 0.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this should work:

```
<c:set var="p" value="${page}" /> <%-- current page --%>
<c:set var="l" value="5" /> <%-- amount of page links to be displayed --%>
<c:set var="r" value="2" /> <%-- minimum link range ahead/behind --%>
<c:set var="t" value="${pageCount}" /> <%-- total amount of pages --%>

<c:set var="begin" value="${t > l ? ((p - r) > 1 ? (p - r): 1): 1}"/>
<c:set var="end" value="${t > l ? ((p + r) > t ? t: (p + r)): t}"/>
```

Comment: Obviously replace ${page} and ${pageCount} with your own attributes.

Comment: You have your first condition backwards, "t > l". Should be reversed.